# What services require Internet Explore 9

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

This may seem a little localised, but as of today (2011-06-01) what services require the client workstation to be running Internet Explorer 2009?

I'm trying to decide if I should allow a metric-butt-load of workstations to be upgraded to IE 9 or if I can hold them back at IE7 or IE8 for a while.

I've got an old ActiveX application that has problems on IE9, and I'm trying to decide if I need to upgrade/re-write it now, or whether I can hold off until it's replacement is ready (a couple years away at least).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any site requires IE 9 any more than any site requires firefox.  It all depends on what standards you need to support.  The reason to upgrade to IE9 is to improve browser security and increase standards support and performance.  If your site works in IE 7 it should work under IE 9 with minimal tweaking due to the compatability mode setting which can be set on the site as a directive.

Answer (score 1):

No mainstream website requires IE9 as of today.

However, some websites will soon require **IE8** or higher e. g. Google Docs: http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2011/06/our-plans-to-support-modern-browsers.html

> I've got an old ActiveX application.

That should work in one of the compatibility modes:

http://wiki.imacros.net/IE9_Nags#How_to_check_what_compatibility_mode_IE9_currently_has.3F

Comment: google docs is a web application, not a website, but it good to point out that apps may have requirements.  I suspect that if google docs ever gets popular the "one version behind" policy will go away quick as they try to get enterprise customers - who usually upgrade every 8 years or so